# firebase <<your connectionis not secure>>

Tags: firebase

Tengo unos problemas con el hosting de Firebase.

Conecte mi dominio personalizado en firebase y todo funcionaba correctamente, la aplicación accedía correctamente.
No fue hasta después al hacer la prueba en otra computadora (con el cliente), que salio que mi conexión no era segura y rompía el https... resulta que después lo volví a probar y accedía correctamente, pero eso no es todo ya que al parecer funciona intermitentemente, en ocaciones entra y en otras me dice que mi conexión no es privada.

La pregunta es ¿Saben por que esta pasando que en ocasiones no me permite acceder diciendo que la conexión no es segura?

Comment: No se que este fallando ya que si fuera un error grave, considero que ni siquiera entraría nunca bien a la aplicación.

Comment: parece más un problema de proxy, puede ser que falle específicamente en la red de alguna empresa, universidad?

Comment: Ya antes habíamos trabajado con el hosting de firebase, era realmente sencillo, sin embargo este nuevo cliente trabaja su pagina con wordpress (un horror) y por lo que he estado leyendo wordpress y firebase no se llevan muy bien. Sin embargo aun no comprendo del todo bien este error o por que es que aparece.